# Google sheet - get crypto currency price from Cryptobridge Exchange API

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-custom-function

How can I retrieve only the price from this API in a Google spreadsheet? This is the API ticker - https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker

For example, if I use this function

> =INDEX(IMPORTDATA("https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker"), 1,7)

then in response I will get following response.

> last:"0.00001993"

Which is the price of PRTX_BTC currency pair which is second in list.

How can I get only price and remove everything except for the price like last, semi column, and double quotes? In response I only want this. How can I get this?

> 0.00001993

Comment: If you've lost the cookie that gives you access to your account, please use the Contact Us link below to regain access.

Answer (score -1):

Just use importjson function with the specific ticker (https://api.crypto-bridge.org/api/v1/ticker/PRTX_BTC)